# Problems getting HDF5 to work with pyTables

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, hdf5, pytables

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to set up pyTables on OSX 10.8.  I'm running the Enthought python distribution, have installed pyTables and numexpr with PIP, and used Homebrew to install the HDF5 package.

However, when I try to import tables in python, I get the following error:

```
In [7]: import tables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-389ecae14f10> in <module>()
----> 1 import tables

/Users/MYNAME/src/tables/tables/__init__.py in <module>()
     28 
     29 # Necessary imports to get versions stored on the Pyrex extension
---> 30 from tables.utilsExtension import getPyTablesVersion, getHDF5Version
     31 
     32 

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/MYNAME/src/tables/tables/utilsExtension.so, 2): Symbol not         found: _H5E_CALLBACK_g
  Referenced from: /Users/MYNAME/src/tables/tables/utilsExtension.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/MYNAME/src/tables/tables/utilsExtension.so
```

I've tried playing around with my path variable, since I thought that maybe the homebrew directories were getting overwritten or something, but this doesn't seem to be the case.  Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: which HDF5 version did you install ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I downloadedtra hdf5 version 1.8.4, installed it from the source code, and then downloaded the source version of pytables 2.4, not 3.0.0, and installed it using the command:
"sudo python setup.py install --hdf5=download_folder/hdf5-1.8.4/hdf5"
where download_folder is the folder you've downloaded the hdf5 source.
The magic was to install pytables 2.4, not 3.0.